# How get Advantage Database Server installed license count in Delphi Code

Tags: delphi, advantage-database-server

I would like to be able to get the number of installed user licenses for an Advantage Database Server instance in code using Delphi.  I have found a function that lets me get the installed version, ie.           ACE.AdsMgGetInstallInfo(dm.AdsConnection1.handle,@stInstallInfo,@usSize);, but not anything that lets me check the license count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`ACE.AdsMgGetInstallInfo`](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage11.1/index.html?master_sp_mggetinstallinfo.htm) API call you mentioned should be the correct call.

After the call the appropriate info is in the [`ADS_MGMT_INSTALL_INFO`](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage11.1/index.html?master_sp_mggetinstallinfo.htm) structure (@stInstallInfo in your example). The field you're looking for is an `UNSIGNED32` called `ulMaxStatefulUsers`.

Answer (score 0):

easiest to use SQL:

```
EXECUTE PROCEDURE sp_mgGetInstallInfo()
```

lets you read out the installation information,

```
EXECUTE PROCEDURE sp_mgGetUsageInfo()
```

the values displayed in the Consfiguration Utiltiy (configured/inUse/maxUsed/rejected).